# Pyppeteer high CPU usage (nearly 50% for one browser)

Tags: python, cpu-usage, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

For some odd reason, running a single Pyppeteer headless chrome browser takes up 50% of my CPU usage (Ryzen 5 2600X). With a medium-high end CPU like that, I should be able to handle far more than a single browser.

Here are my launch arguments:

```
                    args = ['--disable-infobars',
                            '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
                            "--disable-blink-features",
                            '--start-maximized',
                            '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas', '--no-first-run', '--no-zygote',
                            '--disable-gpu']

                browser = await launch(headless=True, handleSIGINT=False, handleSIGTERM=False,
                                       handleSIGHUP=False,
                                       args=args)
                page = (await browser.pages())[0]
```

Based on my research, those are the best arguments I can have to reduce the CPU usage as much as possible. Any other ideas?

Comment: did u find anything?